# Display a notification on Smart watch when I get a push notification on my android phone

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am trying to create an app for Sony Smart Watch which will notify the user on his watch whenever he gets a notification on his android phone. Whenever my phone gets a notification , I need to check whether it is for my app , If yes then call my already running ExtensionService and pass the extras (containing details of the event). Similar to how Facebook and Twitter apps send their notifications to the smartwatch whenever they have a new one. Is there a way by which android can start a service whenever it gets a notification for my app ?

Comment: Services run all the time, say to catch notifications. Doesn't make sense to start a service when you receive a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the SampleNotificationExtension in the SDK samples?  It should show you how to capture notification Events and display them on the watch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart' as Tflite;
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Baby Cry Detector',
      home: BabyCryDetector(),
    );
  }
}

class BabyCryDetector extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BabyCryDetectorState createState() => _BabyCryDetectorState();
}

class _BabyCryDetectorState extends State<BabyCryDetector> {
  late AudioPlayer _player;
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notifications;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _player = AudioPlayer();
    _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    _notifications.initialize(initializationSettings);
    loadModel();
  }

  Future<void> loadModel() async {
    try {
      String res = await Tflite.loadModelFile(
          model: 'assets/baby_cry_detector.tflite',
          labels: 'assets/baby_cry_detector_labels.txt');
      print(res);
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Failed to load model.');
    }
  }

  Future<void> detectBabyCry() async {
    try {
      List<dynamic> recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnAudio(
          audioSourcePath: '/path/to/audio/file',
          numResults: 1,
          sampleRate: 16000,
          threshold: 0.1);
      if (recognitions.isNotEmpty) {
        String label = recognitions[0]['label'];
        double confidence = recognitions[0]['confidence'];
        if (label == 'baby_cry' && confidence > 0.5) {
          showNotification('Baby Cry Detected!',
              'Your baby is crying. Please check on them.');
        }
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Failed to run model.');
    }
  }

  Future<void> playAudio(String path) async {
    int result = await _player.play(path, isLocal: true);
    if (result == 1) {
      print('Audio played successfully.');
    } else {
      print('Failed to play audio.');
    }
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(String title, String message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'baby_cry_detection_channel',
        'Baby Cry Detection',
        'Notifications for baby cry detection',
        importance: Importance.high,
        priority: Priority.high);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: false);
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await _notifications.show(0, title, message, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'baby_cry_detection');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Baby Cry Detector'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Detect Baby Cry'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await detectBabyCry();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).